# Quotient space of Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $Y$ be a finite dimensional closed subspace of $X$ . Let $T:X \rightarrow Y$ be a bounded linear map.

Why is $\dim(X/\ker T)$ a finite number? And if $Y= \mathbb R $ or $\mathbb C$, $\dim(X/\ker T) =1$?

How to prove it? Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

We denote the elements of $X/ \ker T$ by $[x]$, where $x \in X$ and define the mapping $q:X/ \ker T \to T(X)$ by

$q([x]):=T(x)$.

It is your turn to show that $q$ is well-defined, linear and bijective.

Hence $ \dim (X/ \ker T)= \dim T(X) \le \dim Y < \infty$

Comment: For if $x+$ker $T$= $y+$ker $T$, we have $(x-y) \in$ ker $T$. Then q([x])-q([y])=T(x)-T(y)=0 since T is linear. That proves the well-definedness.
Linearity is obvious by the definition of $q$ and $T$.
Surjective is also obvious by the definition of $T(X)$
Injective: In the proof of well-definedness, reversing the argument proves $q$ is injective.
Btw, thank you for answering.

Comment: just like the Homomorphism theorem in algebra.